# Bootsrap 4 beta column ordering between different containers

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Firstly I am sorry for my bad English.

This is my normal grid:

```
-------------------------------
|    A    |    B    |    C    |
-------------------------------
|     D (horizontal menu)     |
-------------------------------
```

It is possible for XS screen like this?

```
---------
|A      |
---------
|D menu |
---------
|B      |
---------
|C      |
---------
```

Sample code [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yPOjNw)

If not possible reorder between different containers how can I do this via javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap `flex` fix.
you can achieve the result with bootstrap if you move your `.menu` to above container and add `order` property like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-flex ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 order-md-1 order-sm-1 order-1" style="height:100px;background-color:#a5a5ff;">A</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-5 col-lg-5 order-md-2 order-sm-3 order-3" style="height:100px;background-color:#fd7a7a;">B</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-3 order-md-3 order-sm-4  order-4" style="height:100px;background-color:#7cd298;">C</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 order-md-4 order-sm-2 order-2  menu">D (ul li horizontal menu)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```